# How does Python interpret its code?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to learn Python. I have learned some Liberty Basic and wanted to know how Python interprets its code. I have noticed with some of my small programs that it runs it in a strange way, and I am not sure how it runs it. In Liberty Basic, it goes from top to bottom. Before I get into any major Python programming, I would like to know how it runs its code. Top to bottom, bottom to top? Any information relating to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of asking a broad and vague question like this, why not post one of your small programs that doesn't run the way you expect, show the part that's confusing you, and ask why it works that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python interprets any given code file top-to-bottom. However, there are many ways that code that be *interpreted* top-to-bottom but not *run* in exactly that way.

For instance, consider the following small program:

```
def foo():
    print("World")

print("Hello")

foo()
```

If you were looking at only the ordering of the `print()` calls in the file, you might expect that the output would be

```
World
Hello
```

But, because the first print statement is inside a *function definition*, it isn't run immediately when the interpreter gets to that line - instead, it's made part of the `foo` function. Later on, when the `foo()` call is made, is when it is actually run, and thus the actual output is...

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: This isn't _quite_ true. For example, `def foo(): print(a); a=2` won't print the global variable `a` when you call `foo()`, as you'd expect  if it always went top-to-bottom; it'll raise an `UnboundLocalError`, because at the end of compiling `foo` it seems that `a` was assigned to and decides it was a local variable throughout the function. But… probably close enough for the asker.

Comment: Also, of course, Python doesn't ever interpret source code; it interprets bytecode, compiling source code to bytecode if it doesn't already have it. But again, probably close enough for the asker.

Comment: Ah, I see. This helps me out quite a bit due to the issues I was having when writing my code. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered reading any book about Python programming? Here's a list of good reads: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/intro/learning/

Python starts executing code line by line from top to bottom, and branches on branching conditions like any other imperative programming language. This shouldn't be too far removed from Basic...

Comment: I actually haven't looked at any books yet. I haven't had the time to go out and find any books or look online. But thank you for the link to the books. :)